# Can we use appositives before the subject?

Tags: word-usage, appositives

1) Good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style--all are basic writing skills.

2) Basic writing skills--good vocabulary,knowledge of grammar, sense of style can be learned by almost everyone.

In (2) the series of appositives are "good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style".

So by definition:
 *The appositive is a noun or noun phrase that modifies another noun*

So it means appositive comes after the subject right?

But my doubt is: Can we use appositives before a subject like in (1) and in (1) which is the subject (i.e noun) that modifies the noun phrases:
"*Good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style*" ?

Comment: The linear position of NP and its appositive is not a criterion for apposition, cf. _"Ed's wife **Lucy**_ (subject NP) is throwing a party on Saturday" ~ "We thoroughly enjoyed _the opera **Carmen**_ (object NP), though the appositive NP always follows the NP it modifies or is anchored to. Crucially, an appositive NP must be a specifying one, not an ascriptive one. In your last example, "good vocabulary", "knowledge of grammar", "sense of style" are not the modifying kind, but supplementary appositives anchored to the NP "basic writing skills".

Comment: In "the great eccentric, Henri Rousseau, died on this day in 1910", the appositive is not following the NP it modifies. Apposition doesn't really care which order the two elements are in.

Comment: Not true. In your example, the appositive is "Henri Rousseau", which is a supplementary appositive and hence is not modifying the NP "the great eccentric", but has it as its semantic anchor. Appositives always follow the NP they modify or are anchored to.

Comment: @BillJ   What do you think of the following sentence: _Anytime I pass Mr. Spivey, my history teacher's, classroom he says, "Hi!"_ Isn't there something wrong with the apostrophe in the apposition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an appositive can come before the noun it renames, but note that an appositive isn't defined merely as a modifier.

Consider the following definitions:

> **appositive** *noun*
> A term standing in apposition
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/appositive)
>
> **apposition** *noun*
> (Grammar) A relationship between two or more words or phrases in which the two units are grammatically parallel and have the same referent (e.g. my friend Sue; the first US president, George Washington).
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/apposition)

By definition, both "my friend" and "Sue" are appositives of each other since they are grammatically parallel and have the same referent. By convention, however, it is the less-specific term that is labelled the appositive. By that convention, the examples in the definition above have the appositive preceding the related noun.

Consider the following examples from [Grammar Bytes](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm#targetText=An%20appositive%20is%20a%20noun,another%20noun%20right%20beside%20it.&targetText=Look%20at%20these%20appositive%20examples,crawling%20across%20the%20kitchen%20table.) (which, incidentally, notes that appositives are a form of *renaming*):

> The important point to remember is that a nonessential appositive is always separated from the rest of the sentence with comma(s).
>
> When the appositive begins the sentence, it looks like this:
>
> > A hot-tempered tennis player, Robbie charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket.
>
> When the appositive interrupts the sentence, it looks like this:
>
> > Robbie, a hot-tempered tennis player, charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket.
>
> And when the appositive ends the sentence, it looks like this:
>
> > Upset by the bad call, the crowd cheered Robbie, a hot-tempered tennis player who charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The bit about *renaming* is at the top of the Grammar Bytes article. It is not explicitly stated in their examples.

Comment: In the _Grammar Bytes_ examples, the appositive is not of the renaming type. In _Mr Johnson, the Prime Minister, has announced a new deal_ either [subject] noun phrase completely identifies the other. But in _Robbie, a hot-tempered tennis player_, 'a hot-tempered tennis player' modifies rather than identifies 'Robbie'. It adds non-strictly-defining information. And although _A hot-tempered tennis player charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket_ is of course perfectly grammatical, **essential** (rather than incidental) information is lost.

Comment: Sorry; tidying. Will delete this note if you C&P. / But note that 'Grammar Bytes (which, incidentally, notes that appositives are a form of renaming)' is making  a claim for **all** appositives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your comments. I agree, though I interpret *renaming* somewhat broadly in this context.

Comment: 'Specifying' and 'ascriptive' seems an important classification to make. Lexico and Grammar Bytes fail to explain the two possibilities. Dropping either 'Mr Boris Johnson' or 'the Prime Minister' is reasonable in the (amended) above example, but not dropping 'Robbie'; the sentence becomes vastly less well defined (though, as these are still appositives, grammatical). A grammatical option but overall unacceptable.

Answer (score -2):

If there is a "rule" that an appositive must follow the noun modified, I have not heard of it. It is certainly not a general rule in English that modifiers must follow the word modified. We do not say "the child happy was laughing out loud."

Comment: "... I have not heard of it". You have now!

Comment: @BillJ, in your example of  "Ed's wife Lucy," I would say that "Ed's wife" more probably modifies "Lucy" by distinguishing a particular "Lucy" from the potentially many "Lucies" in the world rather than distinguishing among Ed's multiple wives. If that interpretation is correct, then your "rule" disappears.

Comment: "Army captain" versus "Navy captain" seems to be a very clear example of the modifying noun preceding the modified noun.

Comment: I don't think "army" and "navy" are *appositives* in that context.